# google maps, custom icon of zoom button

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, icons

I'm tring to change the icon of map, I'm using css to custom:

```
.gmnoprint div div button {
    background-color: #0071E3 !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    width: 20px !important;
    font-size: small !important;
}

.gmnoprint div div button img {
    background: url('../../../../../assets/img/plus.png') no-repeat !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

but this not work, currently I'm getting this:

[image]

you can see each botton with background change but not the image, I'm thinking that maybe this is not the better way to do it, you can tell me what can I do for change the icon, I just what a "icon plus and minus with color white and background blue"

Comment: This has been asked already. Do NOT use undocumented CSS classnames and properties. Instead, hide the default buttons and create your own.